# How can I create Single Page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

How can I pass map items (title, category and images) in my id.jsx file.

Basically, I just want to create a single page for my projects. But I can only access post ID. I don't know how to pass other data items.

'Projects folder'

[id].js

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Details = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return <div>Post #{router.query.id}

// Single Project Title = {project.title} (like this)

</div>;
};

export default Details;
```

index.js

```
import { MyProjects } from "./MyProjects";

const Projects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(MyProjects);

 {projects.map((project) => (
          <Link
            href={"/projects/" + project.id}
            key={project.id}
            passHref={true}
          >
            <div className="project__item">
              <div className="project__image">
                <Image src={project.image} alt="project" />
              </div>
              <div className="project_info">
                <h5>{project.category}</h5>
                <h3>{project.title}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
```

Comment: By creating `[id].js`, you're creating another page. You may be interested in extracting a component in which you can pass multiple values as props. Since you say you want a single page, you shouldn't be creating another file in `pages/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to send some "state" along with the route transition. This can be accomplished using an `href` object with the "state" on the `query` property, and the `as` prop to hide the query string.

Example:

```
{projects.map((project) => (
  <Link
    key={project.id}
    href={{
      pathname: "/projects/" + project.id,
      query: {
        id: project.id,
        category: project.category,
        title: project.title
      }
    }}
    passHref={true}
    as={"/projects/" + project.id}
  >
    <div className="project__item">
      <div className="project__image">
        <Image src={project.image} alt="project" />
      </div>
      <div className="project_info">
        <h5>{project.category}</h5>
        <h3>{project.title}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Link>
))}
```

...

```
const Details = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Post #{router.query.id}</div>
      <div>Title {router.query.title}</div>
      <div>Category {router.query.category}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Drew! If I get a job someday, It's bcoz of you.

Comment: But when I refresh the ID.js page, all that passed states goes away. How can I keep it?

Comment: @JuliaSchafer Route state is generally very transient, i.e. it only exists *during* the route transition from sender to receiver. If you refresh the page on the receiver side, the sender doesn't resend the data. If the receiver needs to it can persist the passed state to local state and in the case of page reloads, longer term storage like localStorage. The receiving component would need to manage this.